# Firefox unable to load Cakephp pages

Tags: firefox, cakephp

I am running firefox-44 in Linux Mint 17.3 and Cakephp 2.7.3. A few weeks back firefox started giving me "problem loading page" error when trying to access my Cakephp application. However when my PC is online the cakephp application loads just fine. Google Chrome does just fine.

I have checked again in settings to ensure am not using a proxy,reinstalled firefox but still it cannot load the cakephp pages.
Kindly assist.

Comment: first check if localhost is working on firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. However I already struggled with it and found a solution from [Mozilla.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can)

1. In the Location bar, type `about:config` and press `Enter`.
2. The `about:config` "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise! to continue to the `about:config` page.
3. In the Search field, type `network.dns.disableIPv6`.
4. In the list of preferences, double-click `network.dns.disableIPv6` to set its value to `true`. The default is usually `false`.
   This worked for me.